# How to determine why custom ribbon tab does not appear with page component?

Tags: ribbon

I've defined custom tab  with buttons in elements.xml which shows only on document libraries (RegistrationType="List", RegistrationId="101"). When I use CommandUIHandler for javascript, custom tab shows on ribbon and test commands execute fine. But when I try to move away from CommandUIHandles to Page Component, custom tab does not apear at all.
I always test inPrivate, so cache is clean and there are no errors or warnings in javascript console. Using visual studio debugger I'd convinced that component script loads and initializes well. 
How can I determine what causes this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer. In case of using custom tab, it should be programmatically set to available in server-side code, using delegate control or web part.
Here is an example:
http://makarandrkulkarni.blogspot.com/2010/01/sharepoint-2010-ribbon-customization_09.html

Another thing worth mentioning. If you add Command attribute to your tab, group or something else in Elements.xml, you should handle this command in your page component to get it enabled.

Comment: Would you please mark your solution as answer? It is easier to find out, what's right and what's not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a few times when working with the ribbon that even private mode still didn't work.  I had to hit F12 and run the dev tools and say clear cache for this domain.

Comment: I've tried  to clean cache manually too, with no result :(. May be page component ignores  RegistrationType and RegistrationId attributes, and in this case ribbon behavior should be programmatically defined in page code behind?